# retriving video details with ffprobe in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffprobe

i'm using this command for retrieve video information in ubuntu terminal:

```
ffprobe -show_streams sample.mp4
```

this command show all information about video in terminal, but when i use this command in php and use exec function to retrieve result , return

```
string(0) ""
{}
```

**how i can retrieve result in php ?**

my code:

```
    public function information($ffmpeg,$file)
    {
      $info = exec("$ffmpeg -show_streams $file");
      return $info;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm use exec function to run my command with three argument and return value with second argument:

```
$info = exec("$ffmpeg -show_streams $file",$output,$result);
return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should've read manual on exec first to see that you need to specify a third parameter in order to obtain results. However there's some second parameter in the way so it would be much easier to use **shell_exec()**

Manual shall be your friend:

http://php.net/exec

Answer (score 0):

First time find complete path:
command:

```
whereis ffmpeg
```

my result: `/usr/bin/ffprobe`

```
echo exec('/usr/bin/ffprobe -show_format YOURINPUT ', $output, $result);    
var_dump($output);
```

`$result=` 1 or 0..........[  1 error occurs or 0 Input is ok.]

or use command `ffmpeg`
Please check http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2011/04/12/an-ffmpeg-question-why-phps-exec-doesnt-return-the-command-output/