# How to get video info using ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I want that when user uplaods a video it should be passed through various checkpoints like resolution,  frame rate, bit rate and FOV . So i want to know how can i get all these information about video using ffmpeg in php and store it in array to use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ffmpeg to get video info - why do I need to specify an output file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400248/using-ffmpeg-to-get-video-info-why-do-i-need-to-specify-an-output-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [retriving video details with ffprobe in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751323/retriving-video-details-with-ffprobe-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

To show information about a video file using ffmpeg use below command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4
```

in PHP you can run this command using PHP [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function

```
$command = "$ffmpeg_path -i input.mp4";
$output = [];
$return_code = 0;
exec($command, $output, $return_code);
```